# UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage not working from a non-UnityPlayerActivity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-unity-plugin

Similar to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30850342/1877798), I'm [Building a Plugin for Android](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) which starts a non-UnityPlayer Activity. The issue that I am running into is that UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage does not send any messages to Unity until the Activity finishes (in which case Unity receives all of the messages at once). Is there a way to send messages to unity when UnityPlayerActivity is not the current Activity?

Comment: Is it possible to specify that the message will be `asynchronous` ? That way `UnityPlayer` wouldn't care if there is an activity running.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. UnityPlayer is a `View` and depends on its `Activity` (UnityPlayerActivity), so it would care if an Activity is running; the problem is when another Activity is running.

Comment: I think [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-plugin-problem.181399/) might be helpful. As the guy from `Unity Technologies` says: _When it comes to the UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() call, that should be ok to invoke from any thread - it is an async call that will be picked up by the Unity main thread during the next frame update._

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I think that statement perfectly summarizes the problem. The messages are picked up by Unity, but only on Unity's next frame update (while UnityPlayerActivity is the current running Activity). Still, it makes sense that this would be the behavior, as two Activities can't run simultaneously.